# Помогите молодому дарованию (дцпшнику)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой вот хтмл:

```
<nav class="dotstyle dotstyle-fillup">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="sections">
    <div id="first1"></div>
    <div id="second1"></div>
    <div id="third1"></div>
    <div id="fourth1"></div>
</div>
```

Нужно, считать значение id и якорем записать в href, чтобы выглядело вот так:

```
<nav class="dotstyle dotstyle-fillup">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#first1"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#second1"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#third1"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#fourth1"></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="sections">
    <div id="first1"></div>
    <div id="second1"></div>
    <div id="third1"></div>
    <div id="fourth1"></div>
</div>
```

Помогите нубасу плз)

Comment: http://segfault.kiev.ua/smart-questions-ru.html#grovelling

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
var i,
    section = $(".sections>div"),
    sectLen = section.length,
    navLink = $("nav ul li a"),
    navLen = navLink.length;

for (i=0; i<sectLen; i++) {
  $(navLink[i]).attr('href', '#'+$(section[i]).attr('id'))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="dotstyle dotstyle-fillup">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="sections">
            <div id="first1"></div>
            <div id="second1"></div>
            <div id="third1"></div>
            <div id="fourth1"></div>
        </div>
```